# Taking Data from Form to collection in Backbone

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I am having a very big form which has lot of form columns.
I am putting my form data using this code :

```
             var formData = {};
             $("#newwaitlist div").children().each(function(i, el){
             formData[el.id] = $(el).val();
             });
             var waitdriver= new DriverWaitModel(formData);
             console.log(JSON.stringify(waitdriver));
             this.collection.add(waitdriver);
```

The data is correctly getting taken.
but i am having a small bug in this.

1. Inside my form i also have my buttons and also form that takes options(like drop downs).
   The above code also logs the button value and its id. Is there a way to remove it before adding to the collection ??
2. IS the way i am passing my data to the collection correct ?? or is there a better way of doing the same ??

**Note**
I cannot use backbone-stickit or anyother .. Just with backbone, underscore and jquery we have to do. So ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a check for the type, as in `el.prop('type')`.  Like this:

```
$("#newwaitlist div").children().each(function(i, el) {
    if (el.prop('type') !== 'button') {
        formData[el.id] = $(el).val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer also solved the problem,
But in my case i had also to filter out some form elements that were also of not button type.
So this is how i made it work;

```
if(el.id!="addDriveBtn"===true){
formData[el.id] = $(el).val();
}
```

which ever id you dont want to input you can just filter out.

Worked great...

JavaScript and Backbone just rocks